# AO textures vs libgdx Materials

Tags: libgdx

I have a question about the proper use of Materials in LibGdx. I want to use Ambient Occlusion textures (baked in Blender) for models in my game. Should I use Materials for it? I am not sure because, this kind of texture won't be automatically exporter to FBX (I use Blender), so I would need to add it to the materials later in the code, plus each object (in fact a Node) would need to have a separate instance of a Material. Is it OK to have dozens of Materials?

Please advise what would be the best workflow? I want to avoid misusing the Gdx framework.

Thx

Comment: I've seen in many places the tip of not worrying about optimization until you really need it, I would try getting something to work first and then if it produces perfomance issues think about improving the code

Comment: You're absolutely right. In this case though it is not really a question of optimization (performance). It is more about proper use of the framework - I do not want to violate the overall concept (Materials, Attributes etc.) because it may hit me later on.

Comment: Actually I have realized it's a more general question - how to treat all 'baked' textures (lightmap, AO etc.). Should they be part of a Material? Isn't it so that i.e. AO texture is more an attribute of a Model (Node), rather than a Material?